# pkgrm SUNWusb - whoops

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I stupidly followed some bum advice and ran 'pkgrm SUNWusb' on my sparc Solaris system.  After a reboot, for some strange reason, my USB keyboard and mouse won't work.  Imagine that!

SSH access still works.  I'm fervently hoping there is a simple way to restore the USB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out.  I mounted my Solaris install disk, went into /Solaris_10/Product and found the SUNWusb directory, then 'pkgadd -d . SUNwusb'.  Rebooted, and things are fine.